# (UE4) Access other Objects variables in same World

Tags: unreal-engine4

i have 2 Blueprintobjects in my world and my first BP has a public variable. Is it somehow possible to access this public variable in my secound BP?

Answer (score 1):

If these 2 objects are put in the level, then you can:

1. Set the public variable to be `editable` by clicking the eye icon beside variable's name. After clicking it, the icon would become a yellow open eye.
2. Find the object in `World Outliner`, and in its `Details` panel you can find that variable as editable.
3. Select another object as its value.

(Sorry I'm a bit lazy to post images, if it's still unclear I can add them :p)